# How to dim the Touchbar? It is ridiculously bright

Tags: keyboard, touch-bar

I have my screen at the lowest brightness level, the keyboard without light, and F.lux installed to remove the blue light from my screen. That has a very positive effect on my sleep schedule. Now, on my new Macbook Pro with the touchbar, there is this scandalous lighthouse below my screen. The brightness of that thing is giving me headaches. How can I just make it dimmer?